# Google App Engine Instance Hours and Free Quotas

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

Am using Google App Engine for the first time, but am a bit confused about the 'instance hours' and 'free quotas'. If I go for a 'Frontend' F instance, it says 28 free 'instance hours'. However, the pricing page has this imp info

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/quotas#Instances
[image]

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/pricing#standard_instance_pricing
[image]

Does this means that if I have a single F4 instance running for 7hours, that'll amount to 7 * 4=28 instance hours? Or if I have a single F2 instance running for 14hours, that'll be 14 * 2 = 28 instance hours? Essentially, I'll end up eating up my free daily quota much quicker the higher I go in the instance type?

Comment: Yep, your understanding is correct.

Comment: Your understanding is correct. I have a twitter thread with worked examples and explanations - https://twitter.com/GUI_4_GAE/status/1458961486693371904

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are correct. You can use this [Pricing Calculator](https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator/) to help you estimate the costs in your project.

Additionally, to help you monitor your app costs, you can [create a budget alert](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/managing-costs#create_budget_alerts) to receive notifications when you reach your costs limit.